# Android Crashing due to null Criteria

Tags: android

I have the following code that crashes due to the Criteria being null.

For some reason the String best is null.  Any ideas why?

```
private void startGPS() {
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);

    String best = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Best provider: " + best);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(best, 50, 0, this);

}
```

Comment: What you are trying to implement? Any crash log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getBestProvider(criteria, true)` will only return *enabled* providers. Since you request `Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE` you should get GPS, but if it is not enabled you'll get `null`.

Comment: Yes thank you silly me, I had not got the correct permission in my Manifest so it kept crashing because of that.

Comment: can you please provide the permissions you required? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Permission are :  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

Comment: You should check for `null`. What if user has GPS disabled in settings or device has no GPS?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

"Only providers that are permitted to be accessed by the calling activity will be returned. If several providers meet the criteria, the one with the best accuracy is returned. If no provider meets the criteria, the criteria are loosened in the following sequence [...]"

That means if the criteria is too strict then searches for the next best. So null will be returned if either no providers are enabled, or if you do not have the permission to access the provider.

Check your manifest. Also check the result of [getProviders();](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getProviders%28boolean%29) with false parameter, to see which providers may be available.